# What source control provider for Visual Studio Online with git and VS 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

If I want to migrate an existing git project to Visual Studio Online with a git repo, what should the source control provider in Tools->Options->Source Control->Plug in Selection be set to, Microsoft Git Provider or Visual Studio Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option under Source Control wouldn't make a difference, it is identified automatically based off what you currently have opened in Visual Studio.

You would push your existing Git Repo into VSO. It should be showing Microsoft Git Provider just by opening a Git Repo, wouldn't need to be a Git Repo from VSO.